# What is the difference between libc++ and libc++abi library in LLVM?

Tags: libc++

I saw the two projects are quite related, but what are the differences between them? The official webpage doesn't tell much about it.

I know that ABI (Application Binary Interface) is used to provide low-level binary interface among different platforms. So is libc++abi used to provide different implementations for different platforms, and general interface for libc++?

Would be better go give some specific example, e.g. what are included in libc++abi and what in libc++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), or ABI for short, is intended to provide certain low level functions from which to build the C++ standard library. It is a supporting library that is a separate component from the actual standard library. Along with [libcxxabi](https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/), you may also come across Pathscale's [libcxxrt](https://github.com/pathscale/libcxxrt) or GCC's [libsupcxx](http://wiki.osdev.org/Libsupcxx).

On the other hand, [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) is an implementation of the C++ standard library that can be built using either of the 3 mentioned ABIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So do you mean libcxxabi, libcxxrt, libsupcxx, libc++abi, they are similar and all provide the ABI implementations? And could you give some specific examples,  what are in libc++abi and what are in libc++?

Comment: `libcxxabi` and `libc++abi` are the same thing. The ABI libraries contain support for memory management, exception handling, etc... You can see what [libcxxabi offers](https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/spec.html). `libc++` contains  the actual C++ standard library.