# Unable to build simple C++ app using clang++ on ubuntu

Tags: clang++

I am unable to build a simple hello world application using clang-6.0 on bionic beaver, the build command fails with below error.

```
 clang++-6.0 -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ hello.cc -o hello 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

what is this c++abi library and where can i find it ?? 
Please advise.

Comment: Are you using linux machine ? then use https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdevel/libc++abi-dev link to download lib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between libc++ and libc++abi library in LLVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314177/what-is-the-difference-between-libc-and-libcabi-library-in-llvm)

Comment: Thanks @syam.k it worked.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libc++abi-dev`
command will fix the problem.

If you are using a non-default version of Clang, you will have to install a more specific version, e.g. `libc++abi-12-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ravikumar-Tulugu and @Martin-Valgur. In my case (Fedora) I installed the equivalent that is in package lbcxxabi.